# PouchDB: warning: "no matching index found, create an index to optimize query time"

Tags: pouchdb

I'm using pouchdb module and I have a warning when I search database. Warning message is like this. 
warning: "no matching index found, create an index to optimize query time"

Why do I have such warning? If someone knows a reason and solution could you tell me it?

```js
var querySentenceDoc = {
    _id: '_design/query_sentence',
    views: {
        by_query_id: {
            map: function (doc, ctx) {
                ctx.emit(doc.query_id, doc.sentnece_id);
            }.toString()
        }
    }
};

_this.query_sentence.put(querySentenceDoc).then(function () {
    _this.query_sentence.query('query_sentence/by_query_id', { stale: 'update_after' }).then(function () {
        if (proceedCb) {
            proceedCb();
        }
        return;
    });
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Sentences views maybe a 409, because it already exists?', err);
});




showSentenceIds: function (ids) {
    var param = { keys: ids, limit: 15, include_docs: true};
    return this.query_sentence.query('query_sentence/by_query_id', param);
},

models.showSentenceIds(ids).then(function (_s_ids) {
    sentenceIds = _s_ids;
    callback(null, 0);
});
```

### Heading

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in your design doc:

```
ctx.emit(doc.query_id, doc.sentnece_id);
```

So maybe the index isn't built properly. Try changing sentnece_id to sentence_id.

Also, as you're querying on id's, perhaps you can use alldocs instead. See the paragraph about when not to use Map/reduce:
https://pouchdb.com/2014/05/01/secondary-indexes-have-landed-in-pouchdb.html